# Select specific MNIST classes to train a neural network in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

currently i am looking for a way to filter specific classes out of my training dataset (MNIST) to train a neural network on different constellations, e.g. train a network only on classes 4,5,6 then train it on 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to evaluate the results with the test dataset.

I'd like to do it with an argument parser via console to chose which classes should be in my training dataset so i can split this into mini batches. I think i could do it with sorting out via labels but i am kinda stuck at this moment... would appreciate any tip!!!

Greetings,
Alex

Comment: so you're looking for something like `python myprogram.py 4 5 6` to train on digits 4, 5, 6?

Comment: Exactly! I want to see how the results are if i train the NN on a specific data set from where i excluded digits (e.g. 4 5 6), train it on 0,1,2,3,7,8,9 only, then train it on the digits i excluded previously to check the results and compare if the NN is forgetting the exluced ones or reminds it! I think i could just make 2 separate data sets for this! Any tips regarding my problem would be awesome. I was thinking about creating 2 data sets via argparse which i can then train on!

Comment: Using argparse with the procedure you outlined above would work. It's not clear what you're stuck on though

Comment: Basically im stuck on the condition check... i want to iterate through the labels Array which is a nd Array... (since labels and data is corresponding on MNIST the only thing i need to do is to filter out the data via an index, which i need to find first) `mnistTrainObjectLabels.shape` returns (55000, 10) ... so labels basically hold scalars in the format of: [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] this would be the class "3", how can i compare an integer 3 with those type of scalars?

Comment: Found the answer i guess... `one hot=True` transformed the scalar into a one hot vector :) thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer i guess... one hot=True transformed the scalar into a one hot vector :) thanks for your time anyway!